# MySQL count and grouping results based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

If I have the following data in the table `answers`:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| forum_id | user_id | question_id | answer |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1        | 1       | 1           | A      |
| 1        | 1       | 2           | B      |
| 1        | 2       | 1           | B      |
| 1        | 2       | 2           | B      |
| 1        | 3       | 1           | A      |
| 1        | 3       | 2           | B      |
| 2        | 1       | 1           | A      |
| 2        | 2       | 2           | A      |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

How would I select the tally of answers? To retrun results such as:

```
+------------------------------+
| question_id | answer | count |
+------------------------------+
| 1           | A      | 2     |
| 1           | B      | 1     |
| 2           | A      | 3     |
| 2           | B      | 0     |
+------------------------------+
```

This is what I have at the moment. I know it must use GROUP BY but I'm struggling to return the expected results.

```
SELECT question_id, answer, COUNT(*)
FROM answers
WHERE forum_id = 1
GROUP BY question_id, answer
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what's the difference between your expected answer and the answer you are getting from your query. Your query looks ok.

Comment: I think your expected output is wrong, and your current query is correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Op want to count how many user didnt answer B. In this case 0

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Good catch (if you're right), but IMO the OP should have made this requirement clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.question_id, t.answer, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a.question_id, t.answer
  FROM answers as a, (SELECT 'A' AS answer UNION ALL SELECT 'B') AS t
) AS t
LEFT JOIN answers  AS a ON a.question_id = t.question_id
AND a.answer = t.answer and forum_id = 1
GROUP BY t.question_id, t.answer;
```

- [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c112e/14)

Results:

```
| question_id | answer | count |
|-------------|--------|-------|
|           1 |      A |     2 |
|           1 |      B |     1 |
|           2 |      A |     0 |
|           2 |      B |     3 |
```

Note that:

In your sample data B has 3 entries for question 2, whereas A has no entries for question 2. And ofcourse all for forum =1, so your expected results is incorrect, and I think mine is the correct one.

Comment: This is a very good start but have some issues. **1)** the hard code of `(A,B)`  in the `UNION` I hope OP has the valid answers in a different table so you can do `SELECT * FROM valid_answers` instead. **2)** need to include `forum_id` because is possible `forum2` has a `question = 3` and in this query will appear with 0. Check [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4a9a9/1)